# VIrtualbox: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Tags: debian, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dpkg

Hi guys i recently installed Virtualbox on my Windowsfx 10 laptop.

Before when i had Windows 10 on my laptop Virtualbox runned perfect. But since i did a fresh install of Windowsfx 10. And try to run a VM  on Virtualbox this is the result i get......

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Boentoe.

The virtual machine 'Boentoe' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

My os

```
root@Windows-Fabor:/home/mohamedazizi# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Windowsfx
Description:    Windowsfx 10
Release:    10
Codename:   ulyana
```

This is my sources list

```
root@Windows-Fabor:/home/mohamedazizi# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb cdrom:[Windowsfx 10 _Helloa_ - Release amd64 20200823]/ focal contrib main

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wseverin/ppa/ubuntu focal main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib
```

This error i got everytime when i try to install Virtualbox Extensions pack with

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

```
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack/Oracle_VM_V
irtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: 
error: World writable: '/usr/lib'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPac
kManagerWrap, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1424
 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
Installation error: License key incorrect or unknown problem during installation
.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-ext-pack package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My virtualbox version

```
root@Windows-Fabor:/home/mohamedazizi# VBoxManage -v
6.1.16_Ubuntur140961
```

My Virtualbox config

```
root@Windows-Fabor:~/.config/VirtualBox# ls -l
root@Windows-Fabor:~/.config/VirtualBox# ls -l
total 112
-rw------- 1 root root  1184 Feb  1 14:21 compreg.dat
-rw------- 1 root root  1493 Feb  1 16:20 selectorwindow.log
-rw------- 1 root root  1089 Feb  1 14:42 selectorwindow.log.1
-rw------- 1 root root  1089 Feb  1 14:35 selectorwindow.log.2
-rw------- 1 root root  1562 Feb  1 14:27 selectorwindow.log.3
-rw------- 1 root root  4334 Feb  1 16:41 VBoxSVC.log
-rw------- 1 root root  5097 Feb  1 16:21 VBoxSVC.log.1
-rw------- 1 root root  3916 Feb  1 16:14 VBoxSVC.log.2
-rw------- 1 root root  3916 Feb  1 16:13 VBoxSVC.log.3
-rw------- 1 root root  3916 Feb  1 15:43 VBoxSVC.log.4
-rw------- 1 root root  3915 Feb  1 14:42 VBoxSVC.log.5
-rw------- 1 root root  3915 Feb  1 14:38 VBoxSVC.log.6
-rw------- 1 root root  3915 Feb  1 14:28 VBoxSVC.log.7
-rw------- 1 root root  5388 Feb  1 14:28 VBoxSVC.log.8
-rw------- 1 root root  3800 Feb  1 14:21 VBoxSVC.log.9
-rw------- 1 root root  1690 Feb  1 16:20 VirtualBox.nope
-rw------- 1 root root  1608 Feb  1 16:20 VirtualBox.xml
-rw------- 1 root root 30001 Feb  1 14:21 xpti.dat
```

```
root@Windows-Fabor:~# ls -ld /usr/lib
drwxrwxrwx 147 root root 12288 Aug 25 03:05 /usr/lib
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -ld /usr/lib`.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: The permissions should be `drwxr-xr-x`, that seems to be the cause for the failed installation. Try `sudo chmod go-w /usr/lib` and then `sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack`. I hope this is the only directory with wrong permissions.

Comment: This has done the job ! Thanks big time !!! Pls post it as answer so that i can accept your answer.

Comment: I think the existing answer makes a valid point. You should use the Ubuntu packages since your distribution is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Freddy  Post   it as answer , your comment   solve the world writable problem.

Comment: @GAD3R I really don't mind if you add that to your answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux mint Ulyana is based on Ubuntu Focal Fossa

Change the following line:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib
```

to  ([use `eoan` codename](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)):

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib
```

Then remove the installed virtualbox and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1
sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
```

The main problem is solved from [@Freddy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/332764/freddy) [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632103/virtualbox-ns-error-failure#comment1183076_632103):

> The permissions should be `drwxr-xr-x`, that seems to be the cause for the failed installation. Try `sudo chmod go-w /usr/lib` and then `sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack`. I hope this is the only directory with wrong permissions.